# Idioms restricting subjects

Tags: idioms

I would like to express that restricting the subject in front of the sentence.
What would be the best expression?

The sentence I would write is as follows.

**Talking only about something, it seems A doesn't occur when I changed B to C.**

Please correct me!

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you would be specific about that "something" and perhaps what A, B, and C, are, and maybe also what kind of writing you're looking for. (Even though using *it seems* suggests that your writing is not casual. Then again, *it seems* is probably not the best choice there, but it's not your question. (We don't do proofreading, either.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Focusing on** something, it seems A doesn't occur when I **change** B to C.

**it seems** is expression of current opinion rather than stating what happened in the past, so you should use **change** rather than **changed**.

Comment: "...it seems A doesn't occur when I *change* B to C." Or "...it seems A *didn't* occur when I changed B to C."

Comment: @user3169. Thanks for pointing that out. It should be the former, unless you change **seems** to **seemed** as well.

Comment: @JavaLatte Actually *seems* just indicates an impression, which could have been of a present or past occurrence (*change* in this example).